# BindingSource not updating underlying model

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datasource, model-binding

In my WinForms I have a model with its properties (just plain) and then I have a ViewModel that basically is the same as the model class except it implements INotifyPropertyChanged and calls NotifyPropertyChanged when there is a value change.

Then in my WinForm I have my model instance assigned to the  binding source:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = myModelInstance;
```

Then I call (in the constructor) a method in which I initialize the data bindings like this:

```
 this.textbox.DataBinding.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "FirstName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

When the form loads I see the controls are initialized to the values in the underlying model. HOWEVER, if I change the values on the control (not the model!) and press the OK button, I do:

```
 bindingSource1.EndEdit();
 Close();
```

but the problem is that whatever changes were made in the controls (UI), are not reflected back on the underlying data source object (the model).

What am I missing?

Comment: Changes will be applied to `myModelInstance`. How do you check to see if changes applied to underlying model?

Comment: @RezaAghaei changes are NOT being applied back, when I check myModelInstance it has the original values and not the values shown on the controls.